# Storing the indices of unique elements in a matrix

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

I have this matrix

```
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 1
2 2
3 1
```

From this matrix I want a data structure something of this sort

```
1={2 3 4}
2 = {1 2}
3 = {1}
```

How can I do this efficiently in matlab?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) for that. Let your matrix be denoted `M`.

```
[bb, ~, jj] = unique(M(:,1));
occ = accumarray(jj,M(:,2),[],@(v) {v(:).'});
result = [num2cell(bb) occ];
```

The result is a 2-column cell array. With your example data,

```
>> result{:,1}
ans =
     1
ans =
     2
ans =
     3
>> result{:,2}
ans =
     2     3     4
ans =
     1     2
ans =
     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Unique nearly gives you the information you want:

```
[a,b,c]=unique(x)
```

where `a` contains the groups [1,2,3] in this case, and c indicates to which group a row belongs. Now you can get a row, using:

```
x(c==1,2) %first row
```

Put this into arrayfun to get all rows:

```
arrayfun(@(e)x(c==e,2),a,'UniformOutput',false)
```